# How to persist when-clause context in VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I followed the document of [when clause context](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#add-a-custom-when-clause-context) and added a custom when clause context.

I set a boolean context:

```ts
let start = vscode.commands.registerCommand('myExt.start', () => {
    vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'myExt.activated', true);
});
```

But after the VSCode restarts, even if `myExt.activated` is `true`. VSCode forget it...

```json
"explorer/context": [
    {
        "command": "myExt.filter",
        "when": "myExt.activated"
    }
]
```

Not showing after VSCode restarts even if `myExt.activated` was `true` in the last time...

Also, when debugging the context with the `Developer: Inspect Context Keys` command, the `myExt.activated` is not there.

Is there any way to persist when-clause context between VSCode restarts?

Comment: Use the `globalStorageUri` and `globalState` from the `ExtensionContext` https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext

Comment: I'm using `workspaceState` already for something else, since I want workspace scope. But I didn't succeed to use it in `when-clause` (doesn't appear in context keys)

Comment: Is there some reason you do not just execute the `setContext` command whenever your extension is activated?  You are doing it by a command now - just do the execute part at the top of your `activate` function.

Comment: That's true. But as you can see, I'm contributing to `explorer/context` and executing `setContext` on activation means - I must to register to `*` or `onStartupFinished` just for executing the `setContext`, I think it is unnecessary and want to avoid it. Another "issue" is the menu is not accessible until the activation completed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the answers appear in the comments (by @rioV8 and @Mark) I will summarize them here:

For storing persist data there are `globalState` and `workspaceState` (from the `ExtensionContext`).

For storing persist context we have to use `globalState` or `workspaceState` to store the state and register to `*` or `onStartupFinished` activation events and immediately call `setContext` with the state for the persist storage.